# Clone and restore "tooltiped" elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm in trouble with restoring DOM structure that has elements passed to Bootstrap's `.fn.tooltip()` method.

To be specific: `$('footer p')` is passed to tooltip on document ready event, like this:

```
$(function(){

$('footer p').tooltip();
$('footer p').on('click', function(){
console.log('Just to test events')
});

})
```

I check it out, tooltip works, on click console message appears. Now I take backup of what am I about to delete and delete it, from console, by calling function:

```
function experiment_destroy() {
window.backup = $('footer').clone(true, true);
$('footer p').remove();
}
```

as expected, footer's `p` disappears.

Now I restore what is cloned and cached in window.backup variable with:

```
function experiment_restore(){
    $('footer').empty();
    $('footer').replaceWith(window.backup);
}
```

also called from console and here's what happens:

- `footer p` element is back as it should be
- `footer p` on click produces console message 'Just to test events'
  message, so *this event is restored* along with element
- **no tooltip is restored**.

Even if I re-call tooltip method in function `experiment_restore` I get nothing. Does anyone have some idea?

**UPDATE:**
I've made one more variation. Tried with different - totally minimal DOM environment with just `p` for `tooltip` and parent container element. **Results are the same**. Definitely there isn't just *something* in my complex DOM structure that was messing things up.

Here is [very simple Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/b1u2dzpz/1/).

Comment: Why dont you inialize the tooltip again at the restore function?

Comment: I do ( the second last sentence) - I have tried even with that. But that's not the point.

Comment: Oh yes sorry. Are having any console error or something? Thats odd. It should work. Maybe when you try to re call the tooltip the footer is not loaded yet. Try set a time out to see if theres a problem.

Comment: I wish none of this is true. I've tried even with recalling `tooltip` method inside `experiment_restore` with timeout 100ms...

Comment: No console error, of course.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the scenario you've shown in your question, I would use [`$().detach()`](https://api.jquery.com/detach/) to remove it from the DOM while at the same time keeping the event handlers and the data added to it with `$().data()` intact. In terms of the fiddle you've put in the question:

```
$('#destroy').click(function(){
    var $footer_p = $('footer p');
    window.backup = $footer_p;
    $footer_p.detach();
})

$('#restore').click(function(){
    var $footer = $('footer');
    $footer.append(window.backup);
});
```

Here's an updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/su3qxneL/)

What happens behind the scenes is that Bootstrap uses `$().data()` to add a JavaScript object of class `Tooltip` to your DOM element, and adds a bunch of event handlers. You need to preserve these.

If for some reason, you cannot use `$().detach()`, then you would have to recreate the tooltip by calling `$().tooltip()`.

#### Why is `$().clone(true, true)` not working?

You call `$().clone()` with parameters to deep clone the DOM hierarchy and preserve the event handlers and the data set with `$().data()` so why is it not working? Is it not the case that the clone should have a reference to the `Tooltip` object created by Bootstrap?

Yes, the event handlers *are* preserved, and the clone *does* have a reference to the `Tooltip` object. However, this object it itself *not* cloned. More importantly, it is not adapted to refer to the new DOM node created by `$().clone()`. (So even if jQuery *would* clone it, it would still not work.) It does receive the event that would trigger the tooltip but `Tooltip.prototype.show` performs this check:

```
  var inDom = $.contains(this.$element[0].ownerDocument.documentElement, this.$element[0])
  if (e.isDefaultPrevented() || !inDom) return
```

The `inDom` variable will be true if `this.$element` is in the DOM. However, this refers to the **original element** for which the tooltip was created, not the clone. Since that element is no longer in the DOM, then `inDom` is false and the next line returns, so the tooltip is never shown.

For giggles, take a clone of a DOM element on which you created a Bootstrap tooltip, *do not remove the original element* but add the clone somewhere else on the page. Then trigger the tooltip on the clone. The tooltip will appear on the original element. :)

What I described above is the general way Bootstrap's jQuery plugins work: they use `$().data()` to add JavaScript objects to the elements on which they operate. There's also a `Dropdown` class for dropdowns, a `Modal` class for modals, etc.

Comment: That's the kind of answer I was looking for. Thank you. Now I'm in trouble, since I have to change **a lot** in my code for updating and restoring DOM to comply hashchange navigation concept. I'm in deep sh**t. Cheers.

Answer (score 8):

You need to call the `tooltip()` method again. Optionally you should destroy the tooltip before cloning / removing the item for cleaning up the data.

[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/b1u2dzpz/2/)

```
$('footer p').tooltip();

$('#destroy').click(function(){
    // optionally remove bindings
    $('footer p').tooltip('destroy');

    window.backup = $('footer').clone();
    $('footer p').remove();
})

$('#restore').click(function(){
    $('footer').replaceWith(window.backup);

    // apply tooltip again
    //window.backup.find("p").tooltip();
    $('footer p').tooltip();
});
```

Comment: you add the tooltip to the backuped element and not to the rebuild one... guess that's not what the op wants

Comment: Is just a matter of selector. I think that `$('footer p').tooltip();` will work as well after `replaceWith()`

Comment: Trouble with this answer - although I'm going to accept it if nothing more informative appears  - is that I do not know what actually happens here. Why the hell function attached to click (`console.log()`) is cloned and restored instantly, without any additional steps and tooltip function with it's event bindings fails and need steps @RaraituL described. Do not kill me if I tell you that `tooltip` is not the only case with this problem.

Comment: jquery clone function doesn't work as you might expect. Plugins might save data not only to the element itself, but to private variables, wrappers, and other stuff. jquery clone cannot guarantee that it copies across all the functionality (which might get pretty complex). As a best practice, is better to `unbind` and then `bind` the plugin again when you do DOM manipulation

Comment: `tooltip('destroy');` <3

Comment: For those who use Bootstrap 4 ... the method $.tooltip("destroy") were replaced by $.tooltip("dispose")

Answer (score 0):

As an added answer, I used JQuery's clone method, but I copied all event listeners like `.clone(true, true)`. My issue was that the tooltips were the exact same from the old and cloned elements, but they were in different positions (so hovering over the new one would show a tooltip in the top left corner of my browser).

The easiest fix I could think of that should work for all Javascript, Bootstrap, JQuery forever is:

```js
const target = document.getElementById("random-div-you-want-to-clone-to")
$("selecting").clone(true, true).appendTo(target);

// if you only want .innerHTML of $("selecting")
// you can do $("selecting").children()

const _tooltips = target.querySelectorAll("[data-toggle='tooltip']");
for (const x of _tooltips) {
    const build = x.cloneNode(true);
    $(build).tooltip();
    x.parentNode.replaceNode(build, x);
}
```

So the `.clone(true, true)` will grab all the event listeners, including "mousedown" which is the listener for the tooltips. When you use native ECMAScript's `cloneNode` method, you aren't getting the event listeners, so you need to reset the tooltips.

It's not the most efficient, but I had been working on this for an hour trying to think of something... be my guest in find a more efficient way because this method isn't, but it works. (e.g. use forEach, simply using JQuery directly, etc.).

Edit: you can also use `.children()` to get the innards of `$("selecting")` (i.e. its children) when cloning rather than getting it AND its children.

Answer (score 0):

For those who use Bootstrap 4, the method `$.tooltip("destroy")` was replaced by `$.tooltip("dispose")`